# SQL using top or other commands to pull out data

Tags: mysql, sql

What I am trying to do is pull out data where a student has went to school for  the most consecutive years

Here's an example of data I want to pull lets say...

```
studentID   years
__________|_______
A123        1992
B123        1991
B123        1990
```

In this example if I use top (1) it will just pull the first one same goes for if I target the years it will just pull that one because it's int is 1992 greater than 1991 and 1990. So if someone has went to school more years consecutively but it was years before 1992 how would I pull out the correct student B123?

Comment: Mmm it didn't format my table correctly....If this is to much of a pain to read let me know I will repost.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've understood of the question,
You want to get the Least Value of `Years`.

```
Student            Years
A                  1992
B                  1994
C                  1991
D                  1990
```

So my assumption is that you want D Student with Year 1990

For that, you can

```
Select 
      top 1 Years 
From 
      TableName 
Order By Years Asc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select student
from (
    Select student
           ,year
           ,year - row_number() over (partition by student  order by year) as rnk 
    from tableName
    )
group by rnk
having count(*)>1
order by count(*) desc;
```

Assuming you need students who have attended for more than  one consecutive years..  above query would work.

If your mysql version  is lower than 8.0, then you have to re-write rownumber logic as analytical function are not supported for lower version..

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

For consecutive years, you can do:

```
Select student, min(year), max(year)
from (Select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by student order by year) as seqnum 
      from t
     ) t
group by student, (year - seqnum)
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Note:  this requires MySQL 8+.

For your results, though, you may just want students with the *most* years.  If so:

```
select student, count(*) as numyears
from t
group by student
order by numyears desc
limit 1;
```

Comment: Sir - second query will return students who has more number of entries in table not consecutive ones, Want to know how can we re write this query without using analytic function